# file_get_contents() returns the homepage instead of another page

Tags: php, file-get-contents, simple-html-dom

I am trying to get content from a page using file_get_contents() (or file_get_html from Simple HTML DOM) : http://www.american-cosmograph.fr/seances.html?view=seances&week=2021-10-11

But I always get the content of the homepage (with that URL and also with other pages with no $_GET parameters). Does anyone have a clue why ?

The website is actually using https but I use http because I am on localhost (MAMP), but I don't think it is the cause.
My code works with another website.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: _"The website is actually using https but I use http because I am on localhost (MAMP)"_ - what does the one thing have to do with the other ...? Nothing! Just because you access _your_ local site via HTTP, doesn't mean you can't make HTTPS requests to _other_ sites on the server side ...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to StackOverflow. In order to help us help you, it'd be great, if you could provide an [mre]. Or, in other words, what exactly have you tried? Please show us some code.

Comment: Disable JavaScript in your browser (globally, or for that specific domain), and then load `https://www.american-cosmograph.fr/seances.html?view=seances&week=2021-10-11` in there. Do you see the content you are looking for ...? If not, then PHP doesn't see it either, because it only gets loaded via JavaScript on the client side, and is not part of the initial HTML the server returned in the first place ...

Comment: Thanks @CBroe ; disabling javascript I don't see anything, but the content is only hidden, what I am looking for (movies and sessions) is in the initial DOM

Comment: About HTTPS... Last week when I tried to do file_get_html('https..') I got an error. I then modified my php.ini file to add extension=php_openssl.dll as I read somewhere. It had no effect but maybe it had not been taken into account. I restarted Mamp but maybe I should have restarted my computer ? Now everything works as expected... Thanks @CBroe and Refugnic Eternium for your time

Answer (score 0):

So, the problem was with HTTPS : opening http URL with `file_get_contents` returned the homepage for some reason, and I got a PHP error trying to open the https URL. I modified my local php.ini file to add `extension=php_openssl.dll`, restarted everything, and now the page is correctly read by `file_get_contents` and `file_get_html`